# Fedora rpm vs Redhat rpm?

Tags: docker, rpmbuild

We are performing a docker installation on one of our VMS.

We have doubts whether Fedora rpms specifically in EPEL fedora are similar to those for RedHat 7.5.

Is there any difference (rpm) docker and can we install from fedora repo the redhat docker rpm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have previously installed the hdf5-devel 1.8.13 CentOS rpm in RHEL because I needed it to build two R packages but I would recommend against doing so especially with Fedora rpms.

In your case, there is already a docker RPM for RHEL. Installing Fedora rpms in RHEL can break it as they may have dependencies which you'll also have to install and that can cause dependency hells because other packages will be looking for the RHEL version but you'll have the Fedora version installed. Also, Fedora (and CentOS) rpms are not supported in RHEL.

Also, the EPEL repo is only for CentOS and RHEL. It's not available for Fedora. If you want to see which repo a package comes from, use this command:

```
yum whatprovides package-name
```

In the Fedora/RHEL/CentOS family, you can also see the names of the repos in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`. The repos for each distro will be called or begin with:

```
fedora.repo
redhat.repo
CentOS-Base.repo
```

Along those lines.

Comment: do you know how to see if specific repo is for fedora redhat centos etc? I mean I can see for example epel repo name but not sure if this is for fedora redhat or any other distr?

Comment: @THEGreatGatsby See my update.